# MiKTeX complier driver did not succeed

Tags: miktex, els-cas

I have the following tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
 
\begin{document}
 
  \title[mode = title]{Leveraging social media news to predict stock
    index movement using RNN-boost}

  \tnotemark[1,2]

  \tnotetext[1]{This document is the results of the research project
    funded by the National Science Foundation.}

  \tnotetext[2]{The second title footnote which is a longer text
    matter to fill through the whole text width and overflow into
    another line in the footnotes area of the first page.}

  \author[1,3]{V. {{\=A}}nand Rawat}[type=editor,
    auid=000,bioid=1,
    prefix=Sir, 
    role=Researcher, 
    orcid=0000-0001-7511-2910]
  \cormark[1] 
  \fnmark[1] 
  \ead{cvr_1@tug.org.in} 
  \ead[url]{www.cvr.cc,www.tug.org.in}

  \credit{Conceptualization of this study, Methodology, Software}

  \address[1]{Indian \TeX{} Users Group, Trivandrum 695014, India}

  \author[2,4]{Han Theh Thanh}[style=chinese]

  \author[2,3] {T. Rishi Nair}[role=Co-ordinator,
    suffix=Jr]
  \fnmark[2] 
  \ead{rishi@sayahna.org}
  \ead[URL]{www.sayahna.org}

  \credit{Data curation, Writing - Original draft preparation}

  \address[2]{Sayahna Foundation, Jagathy, Trivandrum 695014, India}

  \author[1,3]{Karl Berry}
  \cormark[2] 
  \fnmark[1,3]
  \ead{karl@freefriends.org} 
  \ead[URL]{www.tug.org}

  \address[3]{\TeX{} Users Group, Providence, MA, USA}

  \cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author} 
  \cortext[cor2]{Principal corresponding author} 
  \fntext[fn1]{This is the first author footnote. 
    but is common to third author as well.}

  \fntext[fn2]{Another author footnote, this is a very long footnote
    and it should be a really long footnote. But this footnote is not
    yet sufficiently long enough to make two lines of footnote text.}

  \fntext[fn3]{K. Berry is the editor of \TeX Live.}

  \nonumnote{This note has no numbers. In this work we demonstrate
    $a_b$ the formation Y\_1 of a new type of polariton on the
    interface between a cuprous oxide slab and a polystyrene
    micro-sphere placed on the slab. The evanescent field of the
    resonant whispering gallery mode (WGM) of the micro sphere has a
    substantial gradient, and therefore effectively couples with the
    quadrupole $1S$ excitons in cuprous oxide.}

 \begin{abstract}[S U M M A R Y]
  In this work we demonstrate $a_b$ the formation Y\_1 of a new type
  of polariton on the interface between a cuprous oxide slab and a
  polystyrene micro-sphere placed on the slab. The evanescent field of
  the resonant whispering gallery mode (WGM) of the micro sphere has
  a substantial gradient, and therefore effectively couples with the
  quadrupole $1^S$ excitons in cuprous oxide. This evanescent
  polariton has a long life-time, which is determined only by its
  excitonic and WGM component. The polariton lower branch has a well
  pronounced minimum. This suggests that this excitation is localized
  and can be utilized for possible BEC. The spatial coherence of the
  polariton can be improved by assembling the micro-spheres into a
  linear chain.
 \end{abstract}
 \begin{keywords}
  quadrupole exciton \sep polariton \sep WGM \sep BEC
 \end{keywords}

 \maketitle
 


\section{Introduction}

This is 

\begin{table}
  \caption{This is a test caption.}
  \begin{tabular*}{\tblwidth}{@{} LLLL@{} }
   \toprule
    Col 1 & Col 2\\
   \midrule
    12345 & 12345\\
    12345 & 12345\\
    12345 & 12345\\
    12345 & 12345\\
    12345 & 12345\\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The cas-dc style along with some additional images have been downloaded from [here](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates.zip)

When I compile the file I get:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Dario\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log
```

I cannot understand why. Any hint on this?

**EDIT**

@Ulrike Fisher and @daleif

I use texworks and Miktex. If I compile the file using pdflatex only it goes through. However, if I make any change, I can re-compile the file only after I remove all the auxiliary ones.

When I use pdflatex+Maketitle+Bibtex it does not work. [Here](https://unimeit-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/dmaimone_unime_it/EW22kqYlZ-FPqR-eY2KGtKYBXAo5xLkMZ2V_eymv1ziL-g?e=4fkfbM) is the log in the latter case.

Comment: It might be an idea to compile through straight `pdflatex` instead of `texify` *just to rule out that `texify` does something it shouldn't

Comment: I have no issues using TeXLive 2021 and the template from the ZIP you linked to. Though it gives me a lot of `hyperref` warnings, but no compilation issues

Comment: @daleif I use Texworks v.0.6.6 and Miktex. It is wired. I still cannot compile it. And I am using pdflatex to compile the file...

Comment: Can you show the actual compilation log not `texify` log (the actually log should be along with your `.tex` file.

Comment: Use only pdflatex, at best in a terminal, to get a better error message. The error messages from texify are bad and meaningless.

Comment: If I use pdflatex only, it goes through. However, if I change something and I try to recompile it again, it does not work. I need to cancel all the auxiliary files first. If I try with pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex it does not go through. I will edit my previous question to include the log when I receive the error message.

Comment: go to the miktex console (user mode) and call the task "Refresh font map files".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Thanks it worked fine.